# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 in Cordova build android

Tags: java, android, macos, cordova

Running the command `cordova build android` to use Cordova to build an Android app failed.

The response is:

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7.1.2+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /Users/Phang/Projects/JAppName/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /Users/Phang/Projects/JAppName/platforms/android/app/src/main/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/properties.gradle
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
Android Studio project detected
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7.1.2+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /Users/Phang/Projects/JAppName/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to /Users/Phang/Projects/JAppName/platforms/android/app/src/main/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/properties.gradle
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Phang/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
```

I am using MacOS 12.5.1, installed Java 19 and Java SE Development Kit 8u341 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java19

My *.bash_profile* file doesn't have anything with Java. What am I missing out to build?

Answer (score 0):

The build process shows that installation is required JDK 1.8, but you install JDK 19

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8
```

Comment: How do I get JDK 1.8? And after installed JDK 1.8 how do I switch to use that version?